# Iframe stealing mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm using a Javascript scroller class on a site that seamlessly takes care of adding a scrollbar to all predefined elements on the page that have overflown content. The client has recently asked that one of these elements contain an iframe so they can easily add interactive content to this area. (I know I know, iframes, but I'm a subcontractor on this job. Not much pull.) Fortunately the content of the iFram is being pulled from the same domain, so I'm able to resize the iframe once the content loads, in turn firing the Javascript scrollbar. In the end it works beautifully—in Chrome.

In Explorer and Firefox the iframe seems to be stealing mouse events as soon as the mouse is over the iframe. So the mousewheel event no longer works. You can still drag the scroll handle to scroll, or click anywhere on the scroll track, but using the mousewheel does nothing. It doesn't even fire the event.

I've seen that others have had similar issues, but haven't found a workaround. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here's the Scroll class for good measure: http://hastebin.com/xisidogiju.coffee

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: nice link, lol. Decaying pastebins are the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse events are tied to windows, iframes are windows. Its a miracle this works in webkit browsers as you say.

You need to pass the eventListener and perhaps eventHandler between your parent window and the iframes when the mouse moves into them.

Some reference about passing objects between iframes: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php.

Answer (score 0):

I could just manage to overcome this problem. You can check the solution mentioned in the jsfiddle mentioned below.

http://jsfiddle.net/6nnMV/358/

Here, I have created a event to listen to the mouse scroll and have binded the event to the iframe.

You can then scroll the parent window or element by using the scrollTop property like

```
$(element).scrollTop($(element).scrollTop+(number of pixels));
```

This will only work when the iframe you are accessing is in the same domain.