# jQuery niceScroll not working while mouse is on tinyMCE

Tags: scroll, tinymce, nicescroll

I have an admin dashboard in bootstrap. Also implemented the nicescroll. But the page is not scrolling while mouse is on the tinyMCE editor.

Comment: Try giving more info on your implementation, what you tried so far. Maybe the code sample of your implementation to see if you made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hi, tinyMCE made an iframe for display content so it steals mouse wheel events, and nicescroll saddly can't detect scroll events.
as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928975/iframe-stealing-mouse-events